# Access resources from referencing project

Tags: c#, .net, localization, resources, .net-assembly

I have the following solution structure:

- Model
- UI

  - Resources

    - File

UI has reference to Model so Model cannot have reference to UI.

Is there any possibility of accessing resources from UI in Model project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources are compiled into the UI DLL, so no. You might consider putting the resources into a specialized Resources project and referencing that from both Model and UI.